# Hyperledger Fabric : test-network client failed to connect

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Currently I am learning hyperledger fabric .I did run on my windows and Ubuntu computer locally the hyperledger fabric test-network and also made some shell script to add new 0rg3,org4 to different channels and also the default mychannel.Apply different chaincode to channel than the default fabcar.

Then I tried to deploy the test-network to our Centos server we have. I installed the latest go,node,npm,docker and docker-compose. As a second step I opened all necessary ports used from the test-network with firewall-cmd.

Then I tried:
 1. ./network.sh up
 2. ./network.sh createChannel

But while creating the channel I get an error

```
+ peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c mychannel --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -f ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.tx --outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block --tls true --cafile /root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
+ res=1
+ set +x
Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client failed to connect to localhost:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceedediled to create new connection: context deadline exceede
```

For fixes I tried many suggested tips. Also I tried downloading the lastest binaries and also the suggested in tutorial.

1. I deleted all docker images from server

> ```
> docker ps -aq | xargs -n 1 docker stop
> docker ps -aq | xargs -n 1 docker rm -v
> docker volume prune
> docker network prune
> docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
> ```

2. `rm -rf fabric-samples`
3. `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 2.0.1 1.4.6 0.4.18`

I also did look into orderer docker container logs .When the command `peer channel create -o` is trying to run I don't get any logs inside the orderer docker container logs.

At the end I tried `setenforce 0` again with no luck.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

## UPDATE

The log from oreder container is

```
2020-05-05 08:15:11.389 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> WARN 001 General.GenesisFile should be replaced by General.BootstrapFile
2020-05-05 08:15:11.389 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 Kafka.Version unset, setting to 0.10.2.0
2020-05-05 08:15:11.389 UTC [orderer.common.server] prettyPrintStruct -> INFO 003 Orderer config values:
        General.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0"
        General.ListenPort = 7050
        General.TLS.Enabled = true
        General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key"
        General.TLS.Certificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt"
        General.TLS.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
        General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        General.Cluster.ListenAddress = ""
        General.Cluster.ListenPort = 0
        General.Cluster.ServerCertificate = ""
        General.Cluster.ServerPrivateKey = ""
        General.Cluster.ClientCertificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt"
        General.Cluster.ClientPrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key"
        General.Cluster.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
        General.Cluster.DialTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.RPCTimeout = 7s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationBufferSize = 20971520
        General.Cluster.ReplicationPullTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationRetryTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationBackgroundRefreshInterval = 5m0s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationMaxRetries = 12
        General.Cluster.SendBufferSize = 10
        General.Cluster.CertExpirationWarningThreshold = 168h0m0s
        General.Cluster.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
        General.Keepalive.ServerMinInterval = 1m0s
        General.Keepalive.ServerInterval = 2h0m0s
        General.Keepalive.ServerTimeout = 20s
        General.ConnectionTimeout = 0s
        General.GenesisMethod = "file"
        General.GenesisFile = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"
        General.BootstrapMethod = "file"
        General.BootstrapFile = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"
        General.Profile.Enabled = false
        General.Profile.Address = "0.0.0.0:6060"
        General.LocalMSPDir = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp"
        General.LocalMSPID = "OrdererMSP"
        General.BCCSP.ProviderName = "SW"
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.SecLevel = 256
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.HashFamily = "SHA2"
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.Ephemeral = true
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.FileKeystore.KeyStorePath = ""
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.DummyKeystore =
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.InmemKeystore =
        General.Authentication.TimeWindow = 15m0s
        General.Authentication.NoExpirationChecks = false
        FileLedger.Location = "/var/hyperledger/production/orderer"
        FileLedger.Prefix = "hyperledger-fabric-ordererledger"
        Kafka.Retry.ShortInterval = 5s
        Kafka.Retry.ShortTotal = 10m0s
        Kafka.Retry.LongInterval = 5m0s
        Kafka.Retry.LongTotal = 12h0m0s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.DialTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.ReadTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.WriteTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryMax = 3
        Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryBackoff = 250ms
        Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryMax = 3
        Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryBackoff = 100ms
        Kafka.Retry.Consumer.RetryBackoff = 2s
        Kafka.Verbose = true
        Kafka.Version = 0.10.2.0
        Kafka.TLS.Enabled = false
        Kafka.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
        Kafka.TLS.Certificate = ""
        Kafka.TLS.RootCAs = []
        Kafka.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        Kafka.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        Kafka.SASLPlain.Enabled = false
        Kafka.SASLPlain.User = ""
        Kafka.SASLPlain.Password = ""
        Kafka.Topic.ReplicationFactor = 1
        Debug.BroadcastTraceDir = ""
        Debug.DeliverTraceDir = ""
        Consensus = map[SnapDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/snapshot WALDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal]
        Operations.ListenAddress = "127.0.0.1:8443"
        Operations.TLS.Enabled = false
        Operations.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
        Operations.TLS.Certificate = ""
        Operations.TLS.RootCAs = []
        Operations.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        Operations.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        Metrics.Provider = "disabled"
        Metrics.Statsd.Network = "udp"
        Metrics.Statsd.Address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
        Metrics.Statsd.WriteInterval = 30s
        Metrics.Statsd.Prefix = ""
2020-05-05 08:15:11.404 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 004 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
2020-05-05 08:15:11.509 UTC [fsblkstorage] NewProvider -> INFO 005 Creating new file ledger directory at /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains
2020-05-05 08:15:11.515 UTC [orderer.common.server] extractSysChanLastConfig -> INFO 006 Bootstrapping because no existing channels
2020-05-05 08:15:11.526 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> INFO 007 Setting up cluster for orderer type etcdraft
2020-05-05 08:15:11.526 UTC [orderer.common.server] reuseListener -> INFO 008 Cluster listener is not configured, defaulting to use the general listener on port 7050
2020-05-05 08:15:11.526 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 009 Getting block information from block storage
2020-05-05 08:15:11.763 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] HandleChain -> INFO 00a EvictionSuspicion not set, defaulting to 10m0s
2020-05-05 08:15:11.764 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] createOrReadWAL -> INFO 00b No WAL data found, creating new WAL at path '/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal/system-channel' channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:11.813 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] Initialize -> INFO 00c Starting system channel 'system-channel' with genesis block hash abfe6f42b6e7d524b6ba93e7961ae73f6d0859ea9d77ef093c152f0efb5f006d and orderer type etcdraft
2020-05-05 08:15:11.813 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Start -> INFO 00d Starting Raft node channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:11.813 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] Configure -> INFO 00e Entering, channel: system-channel, nodes: []
2020-05-05 08:15:11.813 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] Configure -> INFO 00f Exiting
2020-05-05 08:15:11.813 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] start -> INFO 010 Starting raft node as part of a new channel channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:11.813 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomeFollower -> INFO 011 1 became follower at term 0 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:11.813 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] newRaft -> INFO 012 newRaft 1 [peers: [], term: 0, commit: 0, applied: 0, lastindex: 0, lastterm: 0] channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:11.813 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomeFollower -> INFO 013 1 became follower at term 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:11.813 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> INFO 014 Starting orderer:
 Version: 2.0.1
 Commit SHA: 1cfa5da
 Go version: go1.13.4
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2020-05-05 08:15:11.813 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> INFO 015 Beginning to serve requests
2020-05-05 08:15:11.813 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 016 This node is picked to start campaign channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:11.837 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] apply -> INFO 017 Applied config change to add node 1, current nodes in channel: [1] channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:12.814 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Step -> INFO 018 1 is starting a new election at term 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:12.814 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomePreCandidate -> INFO 019 1 became pre-candidate at term 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:12.814 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 01a 1 received MsgPreVoteResp from 1 at term 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:12.814 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomeCandidate -> INFO 01b 1 became candidate at term 2 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:12.814 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 01c 1 received MsgVoteResp from 1 at term 2 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:12.814 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomeLeader -> INFO 01d 1 became leader at term 2 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:12.814 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 01e raft.node: 1 elected leader 1 at term 2 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:13.178 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 01f Raft leader changed: 0 -> 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:13.178 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 020 Start accepting requests as Raft leader at block [0] channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-05 08:15:13.178 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 021 Leader 1 is present, quit campaign channel=system-channel node=1
```

## UPDATE 2

I found out that i get a lot of errors in firewalld after some digging when running systemctl status firewalld

```
May 07 08:40:22  firewalld[1966]: 2020-05-07 08:40:22 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -t nat -C POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o br-39898f55b0a1 -j MASQUERADE' failed: iptables: No chain/targe...ch by that name.
May 07 08:40:22  firewalld[1966]: 2020-05-07 08:40:22 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -t nat -C DOCKER -i br-39898f55b0a1 -j RETURN' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
May 07 08:40:22  firewalld[1966]: 2020-05-07 08:40:22 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -D FORWARD -i br-39898f55b0a1 -o br-39898f55b0a1 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule ...in that chain?).
May 07 08:40:22  firewalld[1966]: 2020-05-07 08:40:22 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -t filter -C FORWARD -i br-39898f55b0a1 -o br-39898f55b0a1 -j ACCEPT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a ma...in that chain?).
May 07 08:40:22  firewalld[1966]: 2020-05-07 08:40:22 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -t filter -C FORWARD -i br-39898f55b0a1 ! -o br-39898f55b0a1 -j ACCEPT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a ...in that chain?).
May 07 08:40:22  firewalld[1966]: 2020-05-07 08:40:22 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -t filter -C FORWARD -o br-39898f55b0a1 -j DOCKER' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
May 07 08:40:22  firewalld[1966]: 2020-05-07 08:40:22 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -t filter -C FORWARD -o br-39898f55b0a1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT' failed: iptab...in that chain?).
May 07 08:40:22  firewalld[1966]: 2020-05-07 08:40:22 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
May 07 08:40:22  firewalld[1966]: 2020-05-07 08:40:22 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -t filter -C DOCKER-USER -j RETURN' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
May 07 08:40:22  firewalld[1966]: 2020-05-07 08:40:22 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/sbin/iptables -w2 -t filter -C FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similiar error like you, the difference is that my fabric client can't connect to the peer node while you can't connect to the orderer node. I've tried v1.4, v2.0 and v2.1.

```
➜  javascript node invoke.js 
Wallet path: /Users/mutexlock/code/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/wallet
2020-05-05T11:34:53.385Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses
2020-05-05T11:34:53.660Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses
2020-05-05T11:34:53.664Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/Users/mutexlock/code/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/mutexlock/code/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1209:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/Users/mutexlock/code/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/Users/mutexlock/code/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
    at callback (/Users/mutexlock/code/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:847:24) {
  code: 14,
  metadata: [Metadata],
  details: 'failed to connect to all addresses',
  peer: [Object]
}
Failed to submit transaction: Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/Users/mutexlock/code/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/mutexlock/code/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1209:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/Users/mutexlock/code/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/Users/mutexlock/code/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
    at callback (/Users/mutexlock/code/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:847:24) {
  code: 14,
  metadata: [Metadata],
  details: 'failed to connect to all addresses',
  peer: [Object]
}
```

Comment: I i am ruining the shell scripts . As i understand you run the java script  code . I never tried calling the the java / javascript / typescript code.

Comment: This is not an aswer. Create a new question if you have a question. See [ask]